# Jetty redirect and context path

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I have an application running on an embeded jetty server. I have defined the context path:

```
ServletContextHandler context =...
context.setContextPath("/dev");
```

I can correctly acces my app http://application.com:8080/dev

When i use the sendRedirect function of the HttpServletResponse like:

```
resp.sendRedirect("/login");
```

The URL formed is not using the application context. It is returning `http://application.com:8080/login` insetad of   `http://application.com:8080/dev/login`

How do i conifgure this path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `sendRedirect()` with a location having a leading "/", it is always relative to the server root, *not* to the application context. To achieve what you want, you have to append the context path yourself, e.g.:

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login");
```

For it to work in all contexts, it is better to encode it:

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath() + "/login"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
resp.sendRedirect("login");
```

Details:
If the location is relative 
without a leading '/' the container interprets it as relative to
the current request URI. If the location is relative with a leading
'/' the container interprets it as relative to the servlet container root.
If the location is relative with two leading '/' the container interprets
it as a network-path reference (see [RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)).